# Change CSS values with WordPress backend UI elements

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have seen in most premium WordPress themes, backend user is allowed to change CSS properties such as `background-color, font-color, font-family,` just withing the backend using certain UI elements.

There's a color picker on the Appearance section and user can change the color of the particular element and save it.

I'm building a small wordpress theme, and I'd like my users also could change CSS values such way.

So, what's the way of doing it ?

Is it something like file writing ? Or dynamic ? (storing CSS in the database? )

`Thanks!

Comment: You can use one of the existing option frameworks (like redux) to create a backend options page. The options are stored in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've built a little option page and I can save the values to the DB. For a example, I can save user entered Hex value as font-color. But, I don't know how to apply it to CSS stylesheet.

Comment: You can generate css styles in <head> section. Most WordPress themes works this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few ways in which you can use the database values:

a) Echo them as inline styles

```
<body style="background:<?php echo get_option('body_background'); ?>">
```

b) Echo them as style rules inside the `<head>` tags:

```
<head>
    <style>
    body {background:<?php echo get_option('body_background'); ?>}
    </style>
</head>
```

C) Use PHP to generate a dynamic stylesheet (this is preferable since the file can be cached, and possibly [compressed](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/compress-css-with-php/)):

**style.php:**

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('path/to/wp-load.php'); // Located in the root of WordPress
?>

body {background:<?php echo get_option('body_background'); ?>}
```

**header.php:**

```
<head>
    <link href="style.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

---

**EDIT (March 2016)**

I ended up creating [wp-dynamic-css](https://github.com/askupasoftware/wp-dynamic-css): a library that allows you to generate CSS from dynamic content, which I believe will be very useful for you. This is how it can be used:

```
// 1. Load the library
require_once 'wp-dynamic-css/bootstrap.php';

// 2. Set the callback function (used to convert variables to actual values)
function my_dynamic_css_callback( $var_name )
{
   return get_theme_mod($var_name);
}
wp_dynamic_css_set_callback( 'my_dynamic_css_callback' );

// 3. Enqueue the stylesheet (using an absolute path, not URL)
wp_dynamic_css_enqueue( 'path/to/my-style.css' );
```

Now let's say you have a file called `my-style.css` with this code:

```
body {
   background-color: $body_bg_color;
}
```

If, for example, calling `get_theme_mod('body_bg_color')` returns the value `#fff`, then `my-style.css` will be compiled to:

```
body {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

This will be printed to the document `<head>`. The benefit of that approach is that any changes made in the Customizer are updated immediately to show the changes take effect in real time.

Comment: Thanks,  if I go with style.php, do I have to configure the server or .htaccess file or any other stuff ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, you have to include WP Core to use `get_option()`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Anyway, I'm in little doubt that, this will cause any performance issues... And I'm creating a commercial theme. So, would you recommend this method ?

Comment: It shouldn't have any performance impact. In fact, it should be faster than the other options since it will be cached by the browsers. On the other hand, printing CSS rules in the document's head (or inline) is a process that will be repeated every time the page loads since it is not cached and will also increase the size of your document.

Comment: @TharinduLucky see my update for a library that I created that I think you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

A way to go about this is to set the CSS-setting as an inline style. Inline styling always overrides any internal or external stylesheets, and in the same time lets those stylesheets provide a default styling if any inline styling isn't present.

Assuming you are using the Settings API (https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to create your custom settings, this would be how it works.

Fetch your setting:

```
//Get the group of options named custom_css_settings, registered using register_setting()
//These are of course example names and could be anything
$custom_css = get_option('custom_css_settings');
//Get the CSS-option for the element named body
$custom_css_body_bg = $custom_css['body_bg'];
```

Apply the CSS to for example the body-tag as inline CSS, if it's set:

```
//If its set, use the setting - if not print the <body> tag without styling
($custom_css_body_bg) ? "<body style='background:" . $custom_css_body_bg . ";'" : "<body>" ;
```

Comment: Thanks!! Yeah, I also think inline css would be a better option since I couldn't find a proper or best practical way to generate dynamic stylesheets. Found few, but not sure they don't have any side effects.

Answer (score 1):

When creating dynamic CSS-files in WordPress it turns out you might need to tweak it a little. The easiest one, according to CSS Tricks, is adding this to your `style.php`:

```
<?php
 $absolute_path = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
 $wp_load = $absolute_path[0] . 'wp-load.php';
 require_once($wp_load);

  /**
  Do stuff like connect to WP database and grab user set values, like:
  ?>
  body {background:<?php echo get_option('body_background');
  */

  header('Content-type: text/css');
  header('Cache-control: must-revalidate');
?>
```

The next alternative is *"..leave the file named style.css, and use .htaccess to parse it as PHP. Just make sure this code is in the .htaccess file (Apache servers only) at the same directory level as the CSS file. Then just use PHP inside it as you would any other PHP file."*

Source: https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/